# method or design pattern for returning values from callback functions

Tags: javascript

So I'm working with a callback function and of course if I `console.log` the returning parameter it shows data, but how do I assign the returning data to an outside variable. The following code below is what I am try to achieve, but it returns undefined. Is there a design pattern to accomplish this? I've tried looking for an answer but not sure what to look for, or is it even possible?

```
var person = (function () {
  function message(messages, callback) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messages, function(response) {
          callback(response);
      });
  }

  return {
    male: message
  };
})();


var me = person.male({
  mydata: {
    firstname: 'john',
    lastname: 'doe'
  }
}, function (person) {
  // of course this works
  console.log(person);
  return person;
});

// does not work
console.log(me);
```

Comment: You need to tell us what person.male does in order to answer this question.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that part

Comment: Did you write the `person` code?

Comment: yes except for `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` thats part of the google chrome extension api

Comment: Just FYI, you can get rid of the anonymous function that invokes the callback, and do this instead: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messages, callback)`

Comment: I must say that I really dislike the way you've defined `person`.  It is NOT easy code to read and can be defined in a much, much less complicated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular code, you have demonstrated that your callback is getting called by the `person.male()` method, but it is entirely up to the design of the `person.male()` function what it does with the return value of that callback.

If `person.male()` calls the callback asynchronously (e.g. sometime in the future), then there is NO opportunity for it to return your return value back from `person.male()`.  If everything is synchronous, then the return value from the callback will only get returned from `person.male()` if `person.male()` was written to do so.  Since it isn't doing that, then it is obviously not written to do so and nothing you can from outside of the `person.male()` code will change how that works.

---

Now, that you've shown the code for `person.male()`, we can see that the callback is called by the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` function and thus the return value from the callback goes back into that function.  `person.male()` is NOT written to do anything with a return value from the callback.

And, judging by the purpose of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, I would say that it probably calls the callback asynchronously which means it is called after `person.male()` has already returned anyway so there is no way to get the return value from the callback to be returned from `person.male()` because `person.male()` returns before the callback is even called.

---

FYI as a sidebar, you could replace your somewhat complicated `person` definition with this much easier to follow code:

```
var person = {
    male: function(messages, callback) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(messages, callback);
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 and good mention about simplifying the code. I think some people use a "module pattern" without really understanding why. I guess it's possible that this is a small snippet of code that does actually take advantage of it, but it sure does seem like this happens quite a lot.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the input. If you were to do this how would you approach it? You seem very knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: @MrPilot - Do you understand that conceptually, you can't return the result of an asynchronous callback from the originating synchronous function call?  It's a timing impossibility.  The callback happens after the originating function call has already returned.  So, with that in mind, you need to back up and figure out what you're really trying to do.  If you're trying to make a new person object that stores 'john' and 'doe' in it and keep a reference to that, then you need a different definition of `person` that creates a new object and returns that and the callback has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for everything. Lastly, are there a good resources you can recommend for design patterns and best practices?

Comment: @MrPilot - I'd suggest browsing all the resources mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The callback function can just set the "outside" variable directly. However, if the callback is called asynchronously, then 'me' will be undefined until then:

```
var me;

person.male({
  mydata: {
    firstname: 'john',
    lastname: 'doe'
  }
}, function (person) {
  console.log(person);
  me = person;
});

// 'me' will be undefined until the callback is called.
console.log(me);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is asynchronous code, so you don't delay the main thread until it gets the function's result. It would be necessary to access the value at `console.log(me)` in your example.